# How do I replace text without using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, dom

Supposed I have a node that looks like this

```
<a>
  <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-collapse"></span>Collapse All
</a>
```

And I want to toggle it to this

```
<a>
  <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-expand"></span>Expand All
</a>
```

If I use `innerHTML` or `innerText` or `textContent` it just replaces the text. My first pass at a solution is

```
function toggleLastTextNode(element, textWhenTrue, textWhenFalse, value) {
  element.removeChild(obj.childNodes[1]);
  element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", value ? textWhenTrue: textWhenFalse);
}
```

As I know where the text is, it's always the `obj.childNodes[1]` so I just remove it and replace it. The function call would be something like this

```
toggleLastTextNode(element,"Expand","Collapse",true)
```

With the current HTML is there a better way to do this? I want to avoid innerHTML if I can.

Comment: If you're not dealing with several languages, a CSS pseudo-element `::before` or `::after` might also do the trick, leaving that semantically useless text out of your HTML

Comment: Thanks for the tip that looks like a nicer solution, I guess something like a [css3 toggle switch](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-toggle-switch/)?

Comment: I made it an answer as an alternative. Working through the classes has the advantage of letting you switch text and image/whatever style at the same time, while the other way you need to address those changes in several instructions. I made it in jQuery for quick response, but it can also be done in vanillaJS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
document.getElementById('elementid').firstChild.nodeValue = new_text;
```

innerHTML has side effects (like disconnecting existing DOM nodes and rerendering that might be heavy).

Comment: Very nice, that's exactly what I was looking for and that's why I was trying to avoid innerHTML, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays when I'm confronted with this kind of functionality I always try to look at semantic, removing everything which is not content. In this case, you could leave the text in the CSS as it is kinda part of the UX/UI rather than content (a screen reader shouldn't "read" this for example, Google search bot neither, it can't do anything useful with that content). In your case, not changing the HTML (that might also probably be shortened, I come to a solution like this :

**HTML (almost same as yours, added `href` attribute) :**

```
<a href="#">
  <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-collapse"></span>
</a>
```

**CSS :**

```
.glyphicons-collapse::after{content: 'Collapse All'}
.glyphicons-expand::after{content: 'Expand All'}
```

**JS (jquery) :**

```
$('a').on('click','.glyphicons-collapse',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('glyphicons-collapse');
     $(this).addClass('glyphicons-expand');
});

$('a').on('click','.glyphicons-expand',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('glyphicons-expand');
     $(this).addClass('glyphicons-collapse');
});
```

[And the fiddle with all that in it](http://jsfiddle.net/gyup0nqh/)

Comment: Thanks, I've taken this approach (for the css) even though I accepted the other answer. I'm using function that uses ``classList.toggle`` and considering a shim to so I can use the version that allows a second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

define your html content with id

```
<a id="glyphicons">
  <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-collapse"></span>Collapse All
</a>
```

then `toggleExpandCollapse()`

```
var toggleExpandCollapse = function () {
    var oElements = document.getElementById('glyphicons').childNodes;
    if (oElements[1].className === "glyphicons glyphicons-collapse") {
        oElements.childNodes[2].nodeValue = "Expand All";
        oElements[1].className = "glyphicons glyphicons-expand"
    } else {
        oElements.childNodes[2].nodeValue = "Collapse All";
        oElements[1].className = "glyphicons glyphicons-collapse"
    }
}
```